# Want to only add image in the database from the gallery of my phone, but got some problem in between

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to Android Studio. I am trying to add an image from the gallery of my phone to the database of my application. Tried different methods but couldn't succeed.

Here's the XML file for the application.

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

<AbsoluteLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_x="9dp"
        android:layout_y="359dp"
        android:text="Image Name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/image_name"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_x="183dp"
        android:layout_y="355dp"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imgsrc"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_x="11dp"
        android:layout_y="417dp"
        android:text="Image Source:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:text="..."
        android:layout_x="186dp"
        android:layout_y="414dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addbtn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_x="128dp"
        android:layout_y="475dp"
        android:text="Add Image"/>

</AbsoluteLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the database file for the application.

### Databasehelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Flight.db";
 public static final String TABLE_NAME = "flight_table";
 public static final String COL_1 = "ImageName";
 public static final String COL_2 = "Image";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,ImageName TEXT,Image BLOB)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void insertData(String ImageName, byte[] Image) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1,ImageName);
    contentValues.put(COL_2,Image);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
}
}
```

Main java file for the application

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText editImagename;
Button btnAddData;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AddData();

    editImagename = findViewById(R.id.image_name);
    btnAddData = findViewById(R.id.addbtn);

    Button buttonLoadImage = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
}

public  void AddData() {
    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editImagename.getText().toString(),Image.t);
                    if(isInserted == true)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

Comment: What works and what doesn't work? It's difficult to tell just by looking at a wall of code. :)

Comment: i just want to know how the image should be inserted in the database. I got stuck in between

Comment: Don't store images in a database. Store them to the file system, and save their paths in the database instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your activity, you need to obtain the result of the image that the user had chosen. You are already off to a good start with startActivityForResult. So, something like this:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        ...
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

This gives you an image URI to work with, which you can maybe store in a database. Otherwise if you HAVE to store the base64, you could get the resulting Bitmap like this:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Context context, Uri selectedImage) {
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn,
            null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    return (getBitmapFromFileWithCorrectOrientation(picturePath, 4));
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromFileWithCorrectOrientation(String filePath, int inSampleSize) {
    BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    bounds.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, bounds);

    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
    Bitmap bm;
    try {
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, opts);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        BitmapFactory.Options opt2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt2.inSampleSize = inSampleSize * 2;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, opt2);
    }

    int orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
        String orientString = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
        orientation = orientString != null ? Integer.parseInt(orientString) :  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    int rotationAngle = 0;
    if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) rotationAngle = 90;
    if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) rotationAngle = 180;
    if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) rotationAngle = 270;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(rotationAngle, (float) bm.getWidth() / 2, (float) bm.getHeight() / 2);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bounds.outWidth, bounds.outHeight, matrix, true);
}
```

.... and then the base64 code like this ....

```
 public String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat, int quality)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(compressFormat, quality, byteArrayOS);
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

It isnt the BEST code in the world, but it will do what you need.

Comment: Remember to use a decent sample size. If the user chooses a ridiculously big image - you will encounter an exception when you try store the Base64 into the database. You also dont want to choose a sample size that is too large, else your image will look a bit crappy when you load it again.